# Receive data from an observable collection and save / forward

Tags: c#, xamarin, collections, observable, txt

Code written in C#.

I have an observable collection called CartItems that keeps track of all the orders that the customer orders.
For example, is there a way to read data from an observable collection and put it in a txt file? So basically the orders that the customer orders end up in a txt file. This txt file must then be sent to an email address. I have already created the shipping code. So the question is really how do you get data from an observable collection in a method and then put the data in a txt file?

//Observable collection
public ObservableCollection <> CartItems { get; set; }

Comment: You will have to go through the collection like you would with any list, and make a List of strings or just one string and then write the file like you would with any other file.  I don't think there is an automatic way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the items and write them in file one by one like:

```
  public partial class CollectionTest : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<People> peoples = new ObservableCollection<People> {
        new People{ Name="Adam"},
        new People{ Name="Bob"},
        new People {Name="Adam2" },
        new People{ Name="Bob2"} };
        public CollectionTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mycol.ItemsSource = peoples;
        }
        private void On_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {string path= Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "mylist");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
            foreach (var p in peoples)
            {sw.WriteLine(p.Name);
            }
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(path);
                            
        }
```